# INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR - VERSION_MISMATCH - Object version does not match latest database version

Tags: javascript, firebase, request, square, square-connect

I am trying to do update some data in my square inventory using node's `square-connect` package like this:

I am using a `firebase functions` function that executes the code anytime the firebase database gets updated (that is what `export.updateItem` is for, this is the function that executes, and returns a snapshot of the data that got updated):

```
exports.updateItem = functions.firestore
    .document('items/{itemId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        // Get an object representing the document
        // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
        const newValue = change.after.data();
        const previousValue = change.before.data();

        var params = {
            query: {
                exact_query: {
                    attribute_name: "sku",
                    attribute_value: newValue.barcode
                }
            }
        }

        api.searchCatalogObjects(params).then(function(data) {
            console.log('API called successfully in searchFor IDS. Returned data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));

            var dat = data;

            var variation = {
                type: "ITEM_VARIATION",
                id: dat.objects[0].id,
                present_at_all_locations: true,
                item_variation_data: {
                  item_id: dat.objects[0].item_variation_data.item_id,
                  name: "Regular",
                  pricing_type: "FIXED_PRICING",
                  price_money: {
                    amount: Number(newValue.price) * 100,
                    currency: "USD",
                  },
                  sku: newValue.barcode,
                  track_inventory: true
                }
            };

            var item = {
              type: 'ITEM',
              id: dat.objects[0].item_variation_data.item_id,
              item_data: {
                name: newValue.barcode,
                description: newValue.description,
                variations: [variation]
              }
            };

            const idempotencyKey = require('crypto').randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
            var body = {
              idempotency_key: idempotencyKey,
              batches: [{
                objects: [item]
              }]
            };


            api.batchUpsertCatalogObjects(body).then(function(data) {
                console.log('API called successfully in update from EditItem. Returned data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));

                if(newValue.quantity != previousValue.quantity) {

                    var res = data;
                    var variationId = res.objects[0].item_data.variations[0].id;

                    locationApi.listLocations().then(function(data) {
                      console.log('API called successfully in locationApi. Returned data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));

                        var dat = data;
                        var locationId = dat.locations[0].id; // String | The ID of the item's associated location.

                         // String | The ID of the variation to adjust inventory information for.

                        //var body = new SquareConnect.V1AdjustInventoryRequest(); // V1AdjustInventoryRequest | An object containing the fields to POST for the request.  See the corresponding object definition for field details.

                        var adjustBody = {
                            quantity_delta: Number(newValue.quantity) - Number(previousValue.quantity),
                            adjustment_type: 'MANUAL_ADJUST'
                        }

                        inventoryApi.adjustInventory(locationId, variationId, adjustBody).then(function(data) {
                          console.log('API called successfully in inventoryApi. Returned data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                        }, function(error) {
                          console.error(error);
                        });
                    }, function(error) {
                      console.error(error);
                    });
                }
            }, function(error) {
              console.error(error);
            });

        }, function(error) {
          console.error(error);
        });

      return null;
    });
```

The firebase functions log reads like this:

```
9:02:19.367 AM
updateItem
Function execution started
9:02:21.309 AM
updateItem
Function execution took 1944 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
9:02:31.834 AM
updateItem
API called successfully in searchFor IDS. Returned data: {"objects":[{"type":"ITEM_VARIATION","id":"6WNRO7PULPW7Z4QL73FEVITU","updated_at":"2018-08-14T00:53:50.645Z","version":1534208030645,"is_deleted":false,"present_at_all_locations":true,"item_variation_data":{"item_id":"SUW2HSXCNSERMTGERY4Y54TD","name":"Regular","sku":"0637792505002","ordinal":0,"pricing_type":"FIXED_PRICING","price_money":{"amount":100,"currency":"USD"},"location_overrides":[{"location_id":"JN6S37JH6M1Z2","track_inventory":true}],"track_inventory":true}}]}
9:02:47.035 AM
updateItem
 { Error: Bad Request
    at Request.callback (/user_code/node_modules/square-connect/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:675:11)
    at /user_code/node_modules/square-connect/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:883:18
    at Stream.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/square-connect/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/parsers/json.js:16:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Unzip.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/square-connect/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/unzip.js:53:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Unzip.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
  status: 400,
  response: 
   Response {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     res: 
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Object],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '',
        method: null,
        statusCode: 400,
        statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: false,
        req: [Object],
        setEncoding: [Function],
        on: [Function],
        text: '{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"VERSION_MISMATCH","detail":"Object version does not match latest database version.","field":"version"}]}',
        read: [Function] },
     request: 
      Request {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _agent: false,
        _formData: null,
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/catalog/batch-upsert',
        _header: [Object],
        header: [Object],
        writable: true,
        _redirects: 0,
        _maxRedirects: 5,
        cookies: '',
        qs: {},
        qsRaw: [],
        _redirectList: [],
        _streamRequest: false,
        _timeout: 60000,
        _responseTimeout: 0,
        _data: [Object],
        req: [Object],
        protocol: 'https:',
        host: 'connect.squareup.com',
        _endCalled: true,
        _callback: [Function],
        res: [Object],
        response: [Circular],
        called: true },
     req: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedHeader: [Object],
        _contentLength: 526,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /v2/catalog/batch-upsert HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: connect.squareup.com\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Square-Connect-Javascript/2.20180712.1\r\nAuthorization: Bearer sq0atp-on5KcHDr0dhlbefU0EwVwg\r\nSquare-Version: 2018-07-12\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 526\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: null,
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/v2/catalog/batch-upsert',
        _ended: true,
        parser: null,
        res: [Object] },
     text: '{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"VERSION_MISMATCH","detail":"Object version does not match latest database version.","field":"version"}]}',
     body: { errors: [Object] },
     files: undefined,
     buffered: true,
     headers: 
      { 'content-encoding': 'gzip',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'square-version': '2018-07-12',
        vary: 'Origin, Accept-Encoding',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        'x-download-options': 'noopen',
        'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
        'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies': 'none',
        'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
        date: 'Tue, 14 Aug 2018 13:02:39 GMT',
        'keep-alive': 'timeout=60',
        'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=631152000',
        'content-length': '159',
        connection: 'close' },
     header: 
      { 'content-encoding': 'gzip',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'square-version': '2018-07-12',
        vary: 'Origin, Accept-Enco
```

In the `Bad request` info you can see the error is in the `text` attribute:

```
text: '{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"VERSION_MISMATCH","detail":"Object version does not match latest database version.","field":"version"}]}'
```

When I look up data, I see a version attribute that comes with, for example, a square `ITEM_VARIATION`, that looks like:

```
"version":1534208030645
```

You can see it in the object after this text in the output above:

> API called successfully in searchFor IDS. Returned data:

It appears in the data that gets returned when I search for the `ITEM_VARIATION`. I have tried putting this field and value into the `batchUpsertCatalogObjects` request but it doesn't seem to help - I believe I received another error trying to do this (I can't remember what it was, or find it in the logs right now).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I tried adding `version: dat.objects[0].version` to the `item` object but it didn't help.

**UPDATE**

I tried this:

```
var variationObj = dat.objects[0];

variationObj.item_variation_data.price_money =  {amount: Number(newValue.price) * 100, currency: 'USD'};

var item = {
              type: 'ITEM',
              id: dat.objects[0].item_variation_data.item_id,
              item_data: {
                name: newValue.barcode,
                description: newValue.description,
                variations: [variationObj]
           }
};
```

I still get the same error though - even when I use the same exact object that is being returned to me from the query.

**UPDATE**

Above update is what worked - see answer.

Comment: How are you updating the object? Are you retrieving it via APIs and then changing a field in the returned object? If so - it should already have the version associated with it, so you shouldn't receive this error.

Comment: I think i see what you are saying, I am trying to implement your suggestion now by storing the response variation item in a variable and then edit the `price_money` field (the only one I need to edit for the variation) directly on that variable, so that the price changes.

Comment: @sjosey see my update...is this what u meant?

Comment: i am trying to just update the item_variation by itself

Comment: same problem when trying to update item_variation as standalone

Comment: Just so I'm clear - if you try to upsert the `vartiationObj` immediately after changing the price_money (without the `var item...`), you still receive an error about the version?

Comment: actually i think i just got it...`firebase deploy` seems to sometime execute and than not change things actually...im checking it out still

Comment: Cool! Let me know if you figure it out :)

Comment: your suggestions helped...are there some "invisible" aspects to the object? more than just the data it contains...that was missing from the object I was creating and passing through?

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to do the trick was taking the object I needed directly from the response and editing it like `responseObj.xxxxxxx = xxxxxxxx` - instead of trying to create one myself using `{}` notation - and then passing that object through as the necessary parameter. Also, `firebase deploy` seems to need to be rerun sometimes to actually have the changes take effect.

Is also seemed like I needed to use `uspsertCatalogObject` to upload the `ITEM` and `ITEM_VARIATION` separately, instead of including the `ITEM_VARITION` in the `ITEM`'s `variations` field, or using `batchUpsertCatalogObject` with both the `ITEM` and `ITEM_VARIATION` contained in the `batches` array - that seemed to not work either.

Answer (score 0):

According to Square API documentation:

> Version => The version of the object. When updating an object, the
> version supplied must match the version in the database, otherwise, the
> write will be rejected as conflicting.

So when you get the object you will have a property with the version number, you just need to pass that value when updating the catalog object. (in both, product and variant)

Here is an example of the simplest JSON request to update a product catalog using the version field.

```
    "object": {
      "type": "ITEM",
      },
      "id": "7R55G27F2LHH2VUJ7ZONKWRA",
      "item_data": {
        "product_type": "REGULAR",
        "variations": [
          {
            "id": "GQTI2KPZHXNM33QJAJJLAGWC",
            "type": "ITEM_VARIATION",
            "item_data": {
              "name": "cenas variant",
              "product_type": "REGULAR"
            },
            "item_variation_data": {
              "track_inventory": false,
              "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
              "price_money": {
                "amount": 50,
                "currency": "AUD"
              }
            },
            "version": 1637854673484
          }
        ],
        "name": "UPDATE DE PRODUTO"
      },
      "version": 1637854673484
    },
    "idempotency_key": "ffe8498d-6313-45c8-b772-13c2dbc77b4b"
  }'
```